# I've got a problem with The First Conditional sentences

Tags: conditional-constructions

so far I've learnt to use "Will" in the "First Conditional" sentences.
for example we can say:

> If it rains tomorrow, **we'll** go to the cinema.

but can I use **might** instead of **will**?

for example:

> If they like the food, they **might** recommend it to other people.

Comment: Yes, the main clause of real conditionals isn't limited to 'will'. You could use 'might', but it would mean a possibility, rather than certainty (which is conveyed by 'will').

Comment: You might want to look up using might before asking us here.

Answer (score 2):

*If X* can be paired with *then + any modal*; often the "then" is omitted/understood.

When is *if* required?  *Would* (unless it means "will in the past") requires an *if* to either be in the same sentence or understood from context.  Other modals don't have this requirement and sentences with them can exist "standalone".

> We will go to the cinema - Works as an "If x then we will go to the cinema" or standalone, simply saying what will happen.

> We should go to the cinema - Works as an "If x then we should go to the cinema" or standalone.

> We would go the cinema - Needs an *if* unless it's being used as "will in the past".